# where do I put my regex

Tags: jquery, regex, rss

ok I made a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Duayne/nFnEF/

and I finally figured out how to combine my script pieces and remove the links:

```
function setRSSFeed() {
    $('#test').rssfeed('http://www.riogrande.com/rss', {
        limit: 4,
        sort: 'title',
        sortasc: true,
        header: false,
        date: false,
        content: false,
        snippet: false
    }, function () {
        $('#test h4 a').each(function () {
            var $link = $(this);
            $link.after($link.text());
            $link.remove();
        });
    });
}
```

Now I need to insert a regex

```
^.*\b(Gold|Silver)\b.*$
```

So I'll only get the first and fourth lines. Where do I put this line in my code?

Even at that I will still have to figure out how to remove " Metal Price for (date) - "
from those two lines as well.

Any help...Anyone...?

Comment: "where do I put my regex" --- haha, you might imagine what everyone here would reply to that

Comment: Where do you want to "get the first and fourth lines?" How exactly do you expect to provide input and obtain output?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question, don't rely solely on links to external sites. Don't get me wrong, providing a fiddle is _good,_ but sometimes the site is down, so... (I've edited your question to make the jsfiddle link clickable and to copy your function code into the question, but please remember to do this yourself next time.)

Comment: Yes zerkms I did as I wrote that. Thank you nnnnnn I will remember - I'm still trying to figure all this out. I want only the first and fourth lines as my end output to the page. I tried adding 'function (e) { $('h4 a', e).each(function (i) { var title = $(this).text(); if (title== ('^.*\b(Gold|Silver)\b.*$')) $(this).text(title.substring());' before the link removal, but still outputs all 4 lines I wish I knew more what I was doing...all these stabs in the dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to use your regex to only get the two matching lines:

```
        $('#test h4 a').each(function () {
            var $link = $(this),
                text = $link.text();
            if (/^.*\b(Gold|Silver)\b.*$/.test(text))
                $link.after(text);
            $link.remove();
        });
```

That is, in your `.each()` loop you can remove the link every time, but before that only add the text in if the item matches.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nFnEF/1/

To remove the "Metal Price..." part, you can do a `.replace()` with a different regex that captures the two parts you want to keep:

```
        var re = /^(Gold|Silver)[^-]+-\s?([\d.]+)$/;
        $('#test h4 a').each(function () {
            var $link = $(this),
                text = $link.text();
            if (re.test(text))
                $link.after(text.replace(re,"$1 $2"));
            $link.remove();
        });
```

The parts of the pattern in parentheses are capturing matches which you can refer to in the replacement string by number.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nFnEF/6/

Comment: that's what I was missing the "/" on either side ok I think I follow, I'd like to understand more about the why's (guessing it's about looping) but moving on for now...The first solution is great! The second solution by using the capturing group as the output eliminates todays prices. so instead of $1 only - I need to add "+ (a regex for the dollar numbers to 2 decimals)" would that be correct?

Comment: oops wrote that wrong "re" IS the group so INSTEAD of $1 is what I meant...is that correct?

Comment: The `/` on each side is part of JavaScript's "regex literal" syntax - your actual regex goes between them. Sorry, I misunderstood that you wanted to keep the price on the end - have updated the answer to do that. Or here's a version that only keeps two decimal places: http://jsfiddle.net/nFnEF/7/

Comment: OH YES! You are a king of gods in my book!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/nFnEF/3/

you can put the regex inside a $.filter, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setRSSFeed();

    function setRSSFeed() {
        $('#test').rssfeed('http://www.riogrande.com/rss', {
            limit: 4,
            sort: 'title',
            sortasc: true,
            header: false,
            date: false,
            content: false,
            snippet: false
        }, function () {
            $('#test h4 a').each(function () {
                var $link = $(this);
                $link.after($link.text());
                $link.remove();
            });
            $('#test h4').filter(function () {
                    return !$(this).text().match('^(Gold|Silver)');
            }).remove();
        });
    }



});
```